# Only activate VS Code extension when multiple files are found?

Tags: vscode-extensions

VS Code activation points can have:

```
...
"activationEvents": [
    "workspaceContains:**/.editorconfig"
]
...
```

Specified by a glob. Multiple activation events can be specified, but the rule is that "any" of these activation points activate the extension.

I would like the extension to only activate if a list of file names are found in the current worspace, aka. "Projects of our kind include this and that and these."

Is there a way to accomplish that?